# Alguem pode me ajudar a atribuir valor as posições desta matriz com ponteiros?

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Olá, estou com duvida quanto ao seguinte código, ele cria uma matriz bidimensional utilizando ponteiros, a linha de comando que deveria atribuir valor especifico a cada posição da matriz parece não funcionar, pois ao escrever na tela aparece numeros que eu não atribui, alguem pode me ajudar a atribuir valor as posições desta matriz com ponteiros?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int** alocarMatriz(int Linhas,int Colunas){ //Recebe a quantidade de Linhas e Colunas como Parâmetro

  int i=0,j=0; //Variáveis Auxiliares

  int **m = (int**)malloc(Linhas * sizeof(int*)); //Aloca um Vetor de Ponteiros

  for (i = 0; i < Linhas; i++){ //Percorre as linhas do Vetor de Ponteiros
       m[i] = (int*) malloc(Colunas * sizeof(int));    //Aloca um Vetor de Inteiros para cada posição do Vetor de Ponteiros.
        for (j = 0; j < Colunas; j++){ //Percorre o Vetor de Inteiros atual.
            m[i][j] = 0; //Inicializa com 0.
            printf("%d",m);
       }
       printf("\n");
  }
//return m; //Retorna o Ponteiro para a Matriz Alocada
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {



    int Linhas, Colunas;

    printf("Entre com o numero de linhas:");
    scanf("%d",&Linhas);

    printf("\n\nEntre com o numero de linhas:");
    scanf("%d",&Colunas);


    alocarMatriz(Linhas, Colunas);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `printf` não está a mostrar o elemento que acabou de guardar:

```
m[i][j] = 0; //Inicializa com 0.
printf("%d",m); //<---aqui
```

Troque para:

```
printf("%d",m[i][j]);
```

O `m` é um ponteiro para ponteiro, e não o número que acabou de guardar. Para aceder ao numero tem de especificar a linha e a coluna, assim como está na atribuição do `0`.

Se a função `alocarMatriz` é para ser usada no `main` deve colocar o `return m;` que tem comentado, e alterar a chamada que tem no `main` para:

```
int **matriz = alocarMatriz(Linhas, Colunas);
```

Não se esqueça que também tem de liberar a memória associada à matriz quando já não precisar dela, através da função [`free`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

Comment: Obrigado, entendi o pq de usar os indices para a escrita do conteudo das posições da matriz, agradeço!!!